# Responsive email table spacing - Ipad and Iphones Still Showing

Tags: html, iphone, ipad, html-email

**I am developing responsive email for all platforms**

In a table I placed 4 images in `<TD>` and in center `<TD>`  used background color. Further used table collapse for each table. 
For your quick reference code is mentioned below:

But issue I am facing in I-Pad and I-phone is there are slight white lines visible with each circle as you can see in below image.

Your help in this regards will be a great favor to me.
Look forward for your answers at your earliest convenience.

```
<table width="285" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
style="border-spacing:0; background-color:#f0f0f0;">
            <tr>
              <td width="5" height="35" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ><table width="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" height="35" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="em-cr-tp.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="absbottom" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="em-cr-lt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="22" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#D50000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">21</span></td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="em-cr-rt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="em-cr-bt.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;"  /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top"><table width="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" height="35" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="em-cr-tp.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="absbottom" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="em-cr-lt.jpg" style="display:block;" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="5" height="23" border="0" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="22" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#D50000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">21</span></td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="em-cr-rt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="em-cr-bt.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;"  /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><table width="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" height="35" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="em-cr-tp.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="absbottom" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="em-cr-lt.jpg" style="display:block;" alt="" hspace="0" vspace="0" width="5" height="23" border="0" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="22" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#D50000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">21</span></td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="em-cr-rt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="em-cr-bt.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;"  /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><table width="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" height="35" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="em-cr-tp.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="absbottom" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="em-cr-lt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="22" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#D50000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">21</span></td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="em-cr-rt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="em-cr-bt.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;"  /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><table width="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" height="35" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="em-cr-tp.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" align="absbottom" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="em-cr-lt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="22" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#D50000"><span style="color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">21</span></td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="em-cr-rt.jpg" alt="" width="5" height="23" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="em-cr-bt.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" hspace="0" vspace="0" border="0" style="display:block;"  /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><table width="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" height="35" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="em-cr-tp.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" width="35" height="6" border="0" align="absbottom" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="em-cr-lt.jpg" style="display:block;" alt="" width="5" height="23" border="0" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="22" align="center" valign="middle" style="color:#ffffff;font-size:12px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;" bgcolor="#D50000">1</td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="em-cr-rt.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" width="5" height="23" border="0" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="em-cr-bt.jpg" alt="" style="display:block;" width="35" height="6" border="0" align="texttop" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" align="left" valign="top" ></td>
              <td width="35" height="35" align="left" valign="top" style="border-collapse:collapse;"><table width="35" height="35" style="border-collapse:collapse;" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="bottom"><img src="white-lotto-tp.jpg" alt="" width="35" height="6" align="absbottom" border="0" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="right"><img src="white-lotto-lt.jpg" border="0" width="5" height="23" alt="" /></td>
                  <td width="25" height="23" align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#000099"><span style="color:#ffffff;font-size:14px;font-family:Arial;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">14</span></td>
                  <td width="5" height="23" align="left"><img src="white-lotto-rt.jpg" border="0" width="5" height="23" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td height="6" colspan="3" valign="top"><img src="white-lotto-bt.jpg" border="0" width="35" height="6" align="texttop" alt="" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table></td>
              <td width="5" height="35" ></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```

Comment: Did the `vertical-align: middle;` work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try a

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

in the `style` attribute of your image element. If that does not work, it would be great to get the complete HTML and an image that shows the issue.